# JBoss Data Grid library mode with multiple applications sharing caches - what is efficient way

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan

What is the most efficient way of having Infinispan/JBoss Data Grid in library mode with several applications using same caches?

I currently setup JBoss Data Grid in library mode in EAP 6.3, have about 10 applications and 6 different caches configured.
Cache mode is Replication.
Each application has a cache manager which instantiates the caches that are required by the application. Each cache is used by at least 2 applications.

I hooked up hawtio and can see from JMX beans that multiple cache managers are created with duplicated cache instances.
From the logs, I see:

```
ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [pcu-18926|10] (12) [pcu-18926, pcu-24741, pcu-57265, pcu-18397, pcu-26495, pcu-56892, pcu-59913, pcu-53108, pcu-34661, pcu-43165, pcu-32195, pcu-28641]
```

Does it have a lot of overhead in cache managers talking to each other all the time?
I eventually want to setup 4 cluster nodes with JBoss data grid in library mode so how can I configure so that all applications in one node share same cache manager hence reducing noise?
I can't use JBoss data grid in Server mode which I am aware will fulfil my requirements.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I may misunderstand your setup: this log says that there are 10 'nodes'. How many servers do you actually use? If you use the cache to communicate with 10 applications on the same machine, it's a very suboptimal approach; you keep 10 copies of all data and use many RPC to propagate writes between the caches. You should have single local-mode cache and just retrieve a reference to it (probably through JNDI).

Cache managers don't talk to each other, and caches do only when there is an executed operation, or when a node is joining/leaving/crashing (then the caches have to rebalance).

It's JGroups channel that keeps the view and exchanges some messages to detect if the other nodes are alive or other synchronizing messages, but this kind of messages is send once every few seconds, so this has a very low overhead.

On the other hand, each channel keeps several threadpools, and cache manager has a threadpool as well, so there is some memory overhead. From CPU point of view, there is a thread that iterates through the cache and purges expired entries (the task is started every minute), so even with idle cache full of entries some cycles are consumed. If the cache is empty, this has very low consumption (there's not much to iterate through).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I actually use 4 servers but in this example, I've only started one server though.I would like to use replication with dist mode with 2 owners.